# Changed the ProfileImagePath with regedit to the target user folder, it still keeps asking for the old filepath

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, desktop, regedit

I renamed my main user folder

`C:\Users\oldName`

to

`C:\Users\newName`

and then changed the profileImagePath of that user in regedit in `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\microsoft\windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\{user SID}`

to `C:\Users\newName`
but on start up, it keeps telling me that `C:\Users\oldName\Desktop is unavailable.`

is there anything I missed? the profileImagePath edit should have made my desktop to refer to `C:\Users\newName\Desktop`, right?

I was at first having problems with OneDrive, but I unlinked it after moving all its files to where they belong.

until I find a way that works, i'll have to revert my changes, I guess

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, when a user creates a new environment variable, the operating system stores that information in the system registry in the following locations:

```
$User = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment"
$Machine = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment"
```

The operating system copies all environment variables from the registry to the process. Environment variables are always destroyed on program termination and only persist in the system registry, unless they were specifically created in process scope, in which case they are retrieved from the environment block associated with the process. In other words, when an environment variable is created in user scope the current process needs to be restarted in order for the changes to take effect. Similarly, environment variables created in machine scope usually require a restart of the computer.

The problems you are facing now are caused by already expanded environment variables  (e.g. programs that stored `$env:LOCALAPPDATA\My App` in the registry as an important path to find some DLLs, have this path stored as `"C:\Users\$OldName\AppData\Local\My App"`, which doesn't exist anymore on your system.)

At the very least you should look into the `$User` and `$Machine` paths to check if there are any paths for you to update.

Beware though, that you are bound to run into more problems depending on how many applications you already had installed prior to the name change. Some of these paths your program are looking for are stored in JSON or INI files, sometimes even in a database. So if any of your applications stopped working, check if they rely on any paths that are located in the user profile